# how to bind listview selected item to textbox dynamically in wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml, listboxitem

I have 2 columns in my Grid. I will create Button and textbox dynamically in each row. For the dynamic button click, I will show one popup window. The Popup window has some ListviewItems. this is my requirement:
1.If I select any Listview item, it should be displayed on the corresponding textbox.

for example, If it is in the 3rd row, I want to bind the ListviewItem in textbox which is positioned in (Row3, Column1)

this is my xaml:

```
<Grid>
      <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="165" Margin="40,100,0,0"      VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="620">
         <ScrollViewer>
            <Grid x:Name="grid1" Height="auto" Width="580"/>
         </ScrollViewer>
     </DockPanel>
     <Button x:Name="btn_addnewrow" Content="Add" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="69,43,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="89" Height="31" Click="btn_addnewrow_Click"/>
     <Popup Name="popup" IsOpen="False" Placement="Mouse" VerticalOffset="15" HorizontalOffset="0" Margin="124,122,107,65">
        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Background="Coral">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="143">
                <ListView Margin="10,10,0,0" Name="ListView1" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                      VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="194" Height="133" MouseDoubleClick="ListView1_MouseDoubleClick">
                    <ListViewItem Content="Coffie"></ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem Content="Tea"></ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem Content="Orange Juice"></ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem Content="Milk"></ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem Content="Iced Tea"></ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem Content="Mango Shake"></ListViewItem>
                </ListView>

             </StackPanel>
         </Border>
     </Popup>
  </Grid>
```

and this is my code:

```
public partial class DummyTypeofControl : Window
  {
      public DummyTypeofControl()
      {
          InitializeComponent();
       }

    public int count = 0;
    public Button btn1;
    public Button btn2;
    public TextBox txt1;

    private void btn_addnewrow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Creating Rows..
        RowDefinition row0 = new RowDefinition();
        row0.Height = new GridLength(40);
        grid1.RowDefinitions.Add(row0);

        //Creating columns..
        ColumnDefinition col0 = new ColumnDefinition();
        ColumnDefinition col1 = new ColumnDefinition();

        col0.Width = new GridLength(50);
        col1.Width = new GridLength(70);


        grid1.ColumnDefinitions.Add(col0);
        grid1.ColumnDefinitions.Add(col1);

        int i = count;

        //1st Column button
        btn1 = new Button();
        btn1.Margin = new Thickness(10, 10, 0, 0);
        btn1.BorderThickness = new Thickness(0);
        btn1.Name = "btn1_" + i;
        Grid.SetRow(btn1, i);
        Grid.SetColumn(btn1, 0);
        btn1.Click += btnBindList_Click;
        grid1.Children.Add(btn1);

        //2nd column Textbox 
        txt1 = new TextBox();
        txt1.Margin = new Thickness(10, 10, 0, 0);
        txt1.Name = "txt" + i;
        Grid.SetRow(txt1, i);
        Grid.SetColumn(txt1, 1);
        grid1.Children.Add(txt1);

        count++;
    }


    private void btnBindList_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        popup.IsOpen = true;
    }
    private void ListView1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {


        ?
        ?
        ?
        ?

        popup.IsOpen = false;
    }
  }
```

I want to take the rows count and bind listview itms to the corresponding rows textbox dynamically.. i dont know how to continue further.. could any one please help me?

Comment: This would be easy if you were using WPF correctly. We don't generally do things in WPF 'dynamically' like you are. Instead, we create proper data model classes, `DataTemplate`s and use `ICommand`s to implement such functionality. Had you setup your project like this, your requirement could be implemented in a `delegate ICommand` as simple as `SelectedItem.TextValue = SelectedListViewItem.Text`.

Comment: Also you could have all the items declared in the XAML with property visibility=collapsed and then in code behind just show what you want!

Answer (score 0):

Did not quite understand what you wanted, but give this a try.. a bit unconventional.

```
private void btn_addnewrow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
 .....
//let the button know about the textbox
 btn1.Tag = txt1;
}
```

Then, everytime you click on

```
private void btnBindList_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //get the linked textbox and keep it stored int txt1 
    txt1 = ((Button)sender).Tag as TextBox;
    popup.IsOpen = true;
}
```

Then, when you click on on the listview

```
    private void ListView1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        txt1.Text = (ListView1.SelectedItem as ListViewItem).Content.ToString();

        popup.IsOpen = false;
    }
```

There are better and cleaner ways to do this